# How to implement default category (db row) that can not be deleted

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I'm building a CMS (powered by PHP and MYSQL) with pages and categories. Currently users can create, edit and delete pages/categories. But when a user deletes a category, their pages end up in limbo...because the only way they can view pages is by selecting a category.

I'm thinking of designating a default category that cannot be deleted--for orphaned pages. But how would I go about implementing something like that?

Is there a better solution I'm not aware of? I could use some advice.

Comment: Can you prevent the users from deleting a category that has pages still assigned?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I completely forgot that sort of thing matters on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

If each category has a row in a DB, have a field "is_deletable" (a TINYINT should do) and set that to 0 for the default category. This is more flexible than hard-coding the "default" category in.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you delete a category, make an `UPDATE` query for pages in that category, to update the category ID to 0 (which doesn't exist).

Then decide on an `Uncategorized` category, which will contain all pages with category 0.

Answer (score 0):

A user is able to delete the category because you allow it, if you put some requirements to the deletion of a category (if a page belongs to only one category and that's the category the user wants to delete, don't allow it), then they wouldn't be able to delete it.